# Draw a line of desired length and bearing in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

How can I create a straight line when I know the coordinates of the first point, and I know the distance and angle to the end point but I don't know the coordinates of the end point?

Example:

- Start point 1: -44.14984703 -19.82517271
- End point 2: (unknown lat and long) distance => 200km (note: at 75 degrees from point 1)

Note: if there is also a way in which I can discover the lat and long based on the distance from point 1 and the degree (75º), I think it would work too, I just don't know how to apply.

(Translated from Portuguese using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=pt&tl=en).)

Comment: Hello Samuel Rodrigues, welcome to GIS Stackexchange. According to the rules of this site, all questions and answers on this site must be in English. I translated your question; if you disagree with my translation you can use the [edit] link to correct any mistakes I made.

Comment: If you don't want to use library, see answer marked as duplicate. Other possiblity is to use `turf.destination` method of Turf.js library: https://turfjs.org/docs/#destination

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the reply, I will check if they get stuck in my context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you interested in where are aircraft would be after 200km if departing on a bearing of 75 degrees?

The formula using spherical geometry is given here https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(distance/radius) +
                    Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(distance/radius)*Math.cos(bearing) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing)*Math.sin(distance/radius)*Math.cos(lat1),
                         Math.cos(distance/radius)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

OpenLayers uses 6371008.8 meters for the Earth's radius, and lat, lon and bearing must be supplied to the Math functions as radians

Here's a plane departing London on 30° 54' 6" for Tokyo https://jsfiddle.net/50bupyvj/

Comment: I even managed to solve my problem at this link https://turfjs.org/docs/#destination.
My problem is: I am at a certain lat and long, and I would like to know what is the lat and long of a second point that is 200 km away in a course of 75 degrees from point 1.