# Get projection or calculate latitude and longitude from a central point

Tags: openlayers, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a central point (with longitude) and I measure a radius (30º) degrees, I have a distance of 200 KM. Problem: know with precision what is the latitude and longitude of the point that is 200 km from a known point that it is at 30º degrees (heading) a determined central point. Try to find it in several places, and I didn't find it. They even ate me and gave me an answer to a question that I asked previously, only using a library, and I used to research or summarize it all by hand.

Comment: In your comment of the answer to your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348305/draw-a-line-of-desired-length-and-bearing-in-openlayers you stated that you solved this problem with the help of Turf.js library. Why do you ask again?

Comment: @Tomazic, helped me with one last question, but here at the company another need arose in which you will need to do this cycle without using the API.

Comment: And what is wrong with the formula provided by @Mike in his answer? Please, don't be cryptic, explain everything in your question: what you have tried, what worked, what didn't work and/or why you are not satisfied with the result.

Comment: @Tomazic, i am working on route system
where I create several routes according to certain radii, example:
I have 3 addresses between 10 to 20 degrees, then I have 3 more addresses
between 20 to 40 degrees and so on ...

Comment: @tomazicM the first 3 addresses are a route, the second too and so on ...
In order to separate these routes, I want to use openlayers lines starting from the central point (departure)
to the point at the end of each route. So that for me I form this line I want to catch
the address that is the longest distance from the central point and that distance will be my base to separate all routes.
I'll try to put a print.

Comment: You didn't answer why you don't want to use Turf.js library and why you don't want to use formula @Mike proposed in his answer.