# Predict the movement of an object on the map considering geodetic calculations in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I need to represent the movement of an object (which has its own speed) but considering the geodedic calculations. I'm working with EPSG:3857 projection.

How can I do this?

Comment: There's an example of an object going at 959200 meters per second on an initial bearing of 30° 54' 6" at London Heathrow (it gets to Tokyo Narita 10 seconds later) in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348305/draw-a-line-of-desired-length-and-bearing-in-openlayers/348311#348311

Comment: You might also find this OpenLayers example useful: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/flight-animation.html

Comment: Web Mercator should not be trusted for distance or velocity calculation.

Comment: @Mike thank you, this could be a solution!

Comment: @TomazicM here we're trying to simulate an object movement without knowing the destination point... the example you posted is a simulation of movement between declared points.

Comment: @Vince thank you for the info, which is the best projection to work with velocity\distance calculation?

Comment: If you want to perform geodetic calculations, you need a geographic coordinate system (GCS). Any geodesic library could perform the calculations.  @Mike An object travelling at 0.3% of the speed of light in atmosphere is likely to cause destruction until the object is destroyed by friction or is steered into space by the resistance; the damage would likely be restricted to Great Britain. https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/